# How can I blend objects together?

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image]I have 4 objects I would like to smooth/blend together for 3D printing. I did a test print of what I have and it works fine. Now it is time to add some "smooth". My first attempt is failing. I tried a Boolean Union of the vertical column and the sphere but when I try Dyntopo I see a message it is not supported because of the modifier. Without Dyntopo I see no result of the sculpt operation. What would be my best approach to make this a more organic shape or way to blend the interfaces of the objects together?

Comment: If you apply the modifier you'll be able to smooth the join

Comment: Doh! So simple but if you don't know you don't know :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the *Boolean* modifier, as long as you have not applied it the additional part of the object is only virtual. Once done you can sculpt with *Dyntopo* on.